# Data in database does not show up in select query

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with the following data:

```
sqlite> select * from steamUsers;
1|76561198006884566|145992938185424896
2|76561198006884566|145992938185424896
3|76561198006884566|145992938185424896
```

However, when I try to query it via `select * from steamUsers WHERE steamID = "76561198006884566";`, it returns nothing:

```
sqlite> select * from steamUsers WHERE steamID = "76561198006884566";
(no results)
```

If it's helpful at all, here is the schema:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE steamUsers (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,discordID text 
NOT NULL,steamID text NOT NULL);
```

Am I missing something or is there a good reason why this isn't working?

Comment: Isn't 76561198006884566 `discordID`?

Comment: ... Of course I would manage to do something this stupid. I mixed them up on insert and didn't notice because sqlite doesn't list the table headers in the results of a select query,

Comment: To avoid this, type in sqlite: `.headers ON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Making answer from comment by Michal O., to get the question out of the unanswered list.)

According to your schema (providing it turns out to be a very good idea...)
the column 'steamID' is the third, after 'id' and 'discordID'.
The value '76561198006884566' you are looking for occurs several times, but only in the second column 'discordID'.
The only value in 'steamID' is '145992938185424896'.

In short, the values in question does indeed never occur in the column you are looking in.

Comment: @MichaelO. Should you choose to make an answer I will delete mine.